# is-a relation(ERM) to tables

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

i try to design a database with an is-a relation:

Vehicles have some general attributes and the SubVehiclesX have some specialized Attributes.

SubvehicleX is a Vehicle

And a Person has a Vehicle

In the VehicleNames-Table is e.g.:

ID | TableName

1 | SubVehicle1
:

### [image: is - a relation]

Now I want to find out all Attributes of the Vehicle

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM VEHICLE v
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT vn.TableName  
             FROM VehicleNames vn 
             WHERE vn.ID = (SELECT NameOfVehicle 
                        FROM Vehicle v  
                        WHERE v.ID = VARIABLE1)
            ) x on x.ID = v.Vehicle
  WHERE v.ID = VARIABLE1
```

I want it as dynamic as possible, so when i want a new subvehicle i only must insert a row in the VehicleNames and create a new table. I haven't to change my program code.

the part:

```
            (
             SELECT vn.TableName  
             FROM VehicleNames vn 
             WHERE vn.ID = (SELECT NameOfVehicle 
                        FROM Vehicle v  
                        WHERE v.ID = VARIABLE1)
            )
```

must be handled in the Programm code or is there an function to take the Result as a tablename?? Left Join SubVehicle1 x

Is there any other alternative to this? I find this Version isn't clean...

Comment: Why are you creating a new table for every 'subvehicle'?

Comment: The Subvehicles are like car, motorcycle, boat.
When i have 5 cars i don't create 5 tables, i insert them. But when i need a new "class" like a truck i create a new Table

Comment: I figured ... but the question remains, why do you do that? It may or may not be necessary or desirable.  Assuming you have a good reason, you're looking at using either dynamic SQL or writing separate statements for each subtype and choosing which one to execute in the app.  The later is generally wiser.

Comment: Because a boat has other properties than a truck. But some same, like the color or the length.
And I don't want ONE vehicle table with many useless attributes with a "null"-value( e.g. wheels by a boat) and a table with the vehicle type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denormalization to the 'Vehicle' table is still option, technically, but based on the responses in the comments I would probably sub-class it as well. So, you're at the options I mentioned in my last comment.  There's no magic bullet.  It's string concatenation for dynamic SQL or separate statements. One way or another you're going to have to change your app code.